# Having difficulties in understanding Regexp in TCL Language

Tags: tcl, regexp-substr

I am new to TCL language. I am having difficulties to catch data in myFile.txt.

MyFile.txt

```
set obj "{Hello}"
set obj "{Bye}"
set obj "{Nice}"
set obj "{Yoh}"
```

I want to catch words inside the curly bracket as shown below.

```
Hello, Bye, Nice, Yoh
```

How to do it with regexp in TCL.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try would be this simple thing:

```
regexp {\{(\w+)\}} $obj -> word
```

The key points:

1. `{` and `}` are metacharacters inside Tcl's RE language variant, so they need to be escaped.
2. The bit we want to extract (“non-empty word character sequence”, so `\w+`) needs to be captured and matched with a capture variable that comes afterwards: the `->` is just a dummy variable for a capture that we want to ignore.
3. Always put REs in Tcl inside curly braces unless you know exactly what you're doing. (When you know what you're doing, you'll know to put them in braces virtually always anyway.) This allows us to write REs without an inflammation of backslashes.

Comment: It helps a lot!! Thanks!